# How can i read POSTED Json Data in C#.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I want to read data which is posted in JSON in my c#.net application? I am very new with this JSON and POST method?

Can anyone please help me?
I am posting data from page1. to other page2 (smsstaus.aspx in my case) for testing purspoe.
I want to read that JSON posted data in PageLoad of Page2.

Sample code.....

```
 function SendSMSStatus() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myurl/smsstatus.aspx",
        data: '{"SmsSid":"' + $("#<%= txtSmsSid.ClientID%>").val() + '","SmsStaus":"' + $("#<%= txtSmsStaus.ClientID%>").val() + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('update the db here');

        },
        error: function () { }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using ASP with MVC or without it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a *WebMethod* in your smsstatus.aspx (SendStatus for example)
An implementation could look something like this (from the top of my head)

```
[WebMethod] 
public static void SendStatus(string sid, string status) 
{ 
    // retrieve status
}
```

Now you can create a request to consume this method, like this:

```
 function SendSMSStatus() {       
    $.ajax({       
        type: "POST",       
        url: "myurl/smsstatus.aspx/SendStatus",       
        data: '{"SmsSid":"' + $("#<%= txtSmsSid.ClientID%>").val() + '","SmsStaus":"' + $("#<%= txtSmsStaus.ClientID%>").val() + '"}',       
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",       
        dataType: "json",       
        success: function (msg) {       
            alert('update the db here');       

        },       
        error: function () { }       
    });
```

.NET wil deserialize the json string to and pass them as arguments to *SendStatus*

Answer (score 0):

when you are using Jquery and you throw JSON in the data thingy it will change in a normal Post but what you are now doing is gonna give problems change the code to:

```
 function SendSMSStatus() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myurl/smsstatus.aspx",
        data: {"SmsSid":$("#<%= txtSmsSid.ClientID%>").val(),"SmsStaus": $("#<%= txtSmsStaus.ClientID%>").val()},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('update the db here');

        },
        error: function () { }
    });
}
```

and you can use the normal POST but if you want to play with JSON in C# see this aritcle

http://www.drowningintechnicaldebt.com/ShawnWeisfeld/archive/2010/08/22/using-c-4.0-and-dynamic-to-parse-json.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do not change the `contentType` if you want to request the aspx (WebForm) and not the `WebMethod`. (When sending data to the server, use this content-type. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myurl/smsstatus.aspx",
        data: '{"SmsSid":"' + $("#<%= txtSmsSid.ClientID%>").val() + '","SmsStaus":"' + $("#<%= txtSmsStaus.ClientID%>").val() + '"}',
        dataType: "json", // The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. 
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: function () { }
    });
```

Receive data from the `Page_Load` handler,

```
 //Read Form data
 string testData = Request["SmsSid"] + " " + Request["SmsStaus"];

 //Prepare Json string - output
 Response.Clear();
 Response.ContentType = "application/json";
 Response.Write("{ \"d\": \"" + testData +"\" }");
 Response.Flush();
 Response.End();
```